# When its better to write singlethreaded event servers, etc

Tags: c, network-programming, server-side

When its better to write single threaded event or multithreaded or fork servers? Which approach more approriate for:

1. web server who serves statics
2. web server who serves statics and proxy requests to other http servers
3. previous plus this servers makes some logic in C without attending to harddrive or network
4. previous plus makes some requests to MySQL?

For example, the language is C/C++. I want to undestand this question very much. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Given that modern processors are multicore, you should always write code under the assumption that it may at some point be multithreaded (make things reentrant wherever possible, and where not possible, use interfaces that would make it easy to drop-in an implementation that does the necessary locking).

If you have a fairly small number of queries-per-second (qps), then you might be able to get away with a single threaded event server. I would still recommend writing the code in a way that allows for multithreading, though, in the event that you increase the qps and need to handle more events.

A single threaded server can be scaled up by converting it into a forked server; however, forked servers use more resources -- any memory that is common to all requests ends up duplicated in memory when using forked servers, whereas only one copy of this data is required in a single multithreaded server. Also, a multithreaded server can deliver lower latency if it is taking advantage of true parallelism and can actually perform multiple parts of a single request processing in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice discussion on Single Thread vs. MultiThreaded server on [joelonsoftware](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.475678.22),